# Print multiple pages per sheet with space between the pages

Tags: pdf, printing, acrobat

My goal is to print multiple pages/ slides of a pdf document (a handout of a power point presentation) on one sheet, so that one sheet contains two pages/slides. 
Additionally there must be a space between the slides of one sheet. 
The page should look like:

start of the sheet sheet,
page 1 (slide of the powerpoint),
space of about 5cm,
page 2 (slide of the powerpoint) ,
space of about 5cm,
end of the sheet sheet

A further option is that the space between the slides contains an scale paper layout.

Exist there any software which can do that?
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The free and open source tool [pdftools](https://github.com/raffaem/pdftools) can achieve this.

You can put more slides in a single output pdf page using the `--nup` option, ad adjust the space between the slides using the `--delta` option.

Comment: That was exactly the software I have searched 6 years ago. Sorry I have completely forgetten that this question still exist on Stack overflow, but nevertheless thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are several pretty print software utilities out there that have options on saving paper by combining multiple pages onto one sheet.

Your easiest solution however would be to use the operating systems print dialog, which generally has an option for printing multiple pages onto one. To create the space needed you can set scaling of the page to 90% or less if you feel you need a greater border. I just checked this on my MacBook and confirmed this.